# Qt make QSplitter unmovable by user

Tags: qt, qsplitter

how to make make qsplitter unmovable by user and add possibility to enable/disable this function?
Thankyou.

Comment: `QSplitter` is inherent `QWidget` so you can use the [enabled flag](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enabled-prop)

Comment: `your_splitter->setEnabled(false);`

Comment: No. This disables all children widgets too. I want that it acts like a normal layout.

Comment: A long shot but... try disabling the various [`QSplitterHandle`s](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#handle) associated with the `QSplitter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocking the `QSplitter` handler can be done using the [QSplitterHandler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#handle) as @G.M. suggested in the comment.

Here is an example code (assuming you'r using `QMainWindow`)

```
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QSplitter>
#include <QLabel>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QSplitter * poSplitter = new QSplitter(this);
    QLabel * poLbl = new QLabel("Some place holer",this);
    QCheckBox * poToggleSplitter = new QCheckBox("Block splitter", this);

    poSplitter->addWidget(poLbl);
    poSplitter->addWidget(poToggleSplitter);

    connect(poToggleSplitter, &QCheckBox::clicked,
            [poSplitter](bool bChecked)
    {
        // Block splitter movement
        poSplitter->handle(1)->setEnabled(!bChecked);
    });

    this->setCentralWidget(poSplitter);
}
```